# Further subset data frame for embarrassingly parallel processing

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have an embarrassingly parallel problem that I am treating using the [snowfall](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snowfall/index.html) package and its function *sfLapply*.  It works great except that I need a nicer way of splitting up my problem.  My incoming data frame looks like this:

```
Group          Date
1            02/01/12
4            02/01/12
...          ...(31 items)
13           02/01/13
4            02/18/13
5            02/18/13
...          ...(9 items)
22           02/18/13
```

and needs to be split into processing groups by date.  Trouble is, there are only about 5 different dates, so that just using

```
split(processing.groups, processing.groups$date)
```

results in too few parallel jobs.  What I would like is an elegant way to obtain a list where each list element contains no more than, say, 20 entries and yet they are guaranteed to all have the same date.

Example:

```
List Elem 1:  20 items
1             02/01/12
4             02/01/12
...           ...
9             02/01/12
List Elem 2:  14 items
99            02/01/12
17            02/01/12
...           ...
13            02/01/12
List Elem 3:  11 items
4             02/18/13
5             02/18/13
...           ...
22            02/18/13
```

It feels like some tricky listy cutty splitty syntax should be able to achieve this neatly.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is elegant, but...

```
# just to setup a dummy dataframe
z <- data.frame(group=1:200, date=sample(c("a","b","c","d"),200,replace=TRUE))

splitz <- split(z, z$date) # split it once
newsplit <- list() # create something to dump the results into
# split the already split stuff into chunks of <= 20
twicesplit <- sapply(splitz, FUN= function(x){
    newsplit <<- c(newsplit,split(x, findInterval(1:dim(x)[1],(1:20*20))) )
    # the `*20` here would have to be longer if you had more than 400 observations with same date
})
rm(twicesplit) # cleanup unnecessary variable used to suppress printing
```

Comment: It took me a while to decode this one, but it generalizes well now that I get it.  Thank you for introducing the <<- operator to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
mydf <- data.frame( Group= sample(45, 45), 
  Date = rep( c('02/01/12', '02/18/13'), c(34, 11) ) )

tmp <- ave( mydf$Group, mydf$Date, 
    FUN=function(x) rep( seq( ceiling(length(x)/20) ),
    each=20, length.out=length(x) ) )

outlist <- split( mydf, interaction(tmp, mydf$Date, drop=TRUE) )
```

Comment: Clever and more elegant than Thomas' solution.  The use of ave() worked well in this case but not as well when I tried to generalize to non-numeric group variables.

Comment: @BrianB, what problems did you have with non-numeric group variables?  About the only place it is used in my code is to measure its length which should not depend on the type (except maybe for POSIXlt objects).  Factors could behave different then expected with which levels are retained, is that the problem?

Comment: I thought it was going to work (because of the *length()*) also.  However, when I hit it with character types for the groups as well as the dates, I got a bunch of warnings about invalid factors, and NAs in the output.  I'm not actually sure _ave()_ is at fault but for whatever reason it failed.

Comment: @BrianB, the `ave` function is expecting a numeric, so that is what is causing the error.  But if you replace `mydf$Group` with `seq_along(nrow(mydf))` then it works.